# Apache https request status pending for some requests and 502 status is returned

Tags: apache, ssl, tomcat, httpd.conf, mod-ssl

I have deployed the server on EC2 and tomcat. I have purchased the domain from goDaddy. I am using HTTPD with mod_ssl for URL redirect. When I am trying to access my server some request is in the pending state but when I refresh the browser or resubmit the request the data gets loaded.

I have observed only some of the requests fail, regardless of whether I use preworker or worker. I have monitored the tomcat to apache request logs but apache requests are not redirected to tomcat for those requests.

This is now blocking for my production traffic as the user is not able to access this app smoothly.

I have tried to access the app on IP and I face no issue for 502 but when I use it using DNS on https it blocks some request and gives 502.

Currently deployed services-
1. Tomcat
2. Solr
3. Mysql 
4. Apache

System configuration

- RAM 8 GB
- Swap 16 GB
- Core 2

Active users on the system - 100+

[image: for]

> APACHE Config /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
KeepAlive on
StartServers 5
MinSpareThreads          15
MaxSpareThreads         100
ServerLimit 10
MaxRequestWorkers 200
MaxRequestsPerChild 4000

</IfModule>
```

> /ssl.conf

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /mdt http://13.2XX.XXX.XX:9090/appName retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse /mdt http://13.2XX.XXX.XX:9090/appName
</VirtualHost>
```

> Tomcat Config- /conf/server.xml

```
 <Connector port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="120000"
               acceptCount="200"
               maxThreads="3200"
               minSpareThreads="80" 
               maxSpareThreads="160"
               compression="on"
               compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain"   
               redirectPort="8443"
/>
```

Also I have observed that Apache is not releasing the occupied memory that causes server crash I have to monitor and restart the apache when memory reaches the 90%.

Can someone help me !! Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Tomcat comitter here. Is there any compelling reason to use HTTPd at all? Tomcat will perfectly do OpenSSL too.

Comment: @Michael-O Yes. I am using react app and wordpress website which is also deployed on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

I have added below config in apache virtualhost to resolve this issue.

```
< VirtualHost XXXX>
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /mdt http://13.2XX.XXX.XX:9090/appName retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse /mdt http://13.2XX.XXX.XX:9090/appName

 SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
 SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
</VirtualHost>
```